# Why does mice polyreg use so much memory?

Tags: r, memory, r-mice

I'm trying to impute missing genotype data using the R package mice. The first dataset I have consists of a genotype matrix of size 1851x47992 consisting of 0's, 1's and 2's and NA's (most of the entries are 0's), and a phenotype vector of 0's and 1's of length 1851. Since the genotypes consist of 3 discrete categories, I decided to use the polyreg method.

Here is the code I used to try to start the imputation (missing data is stored as -1 in the file; I had to change it to NA):

```
genotype <- as.matrix(read.table('genotype file address'))
phenotype <- unlist(read.table('phenotype file address'))
data3 <- data.frame(genotype,phenotype)
data3[data3==-1] <- NA
library(mice)
imp <- mice(data3,method="polyreg")
```

Unfortunately, I get the error message "cannot allocate vector of size 17.2 Gb", even though the genotype file is only 169MB while the phenotype file is only 5.42KB

I was going to ask about the error itself; but I found several questions already explaining that it means there is not enough room in memory to store the computation. So I'd instead like to ask: 1) Why does this mice-polyreg need 2 orders of magnitude more memory than the size of the underlying data, 2) Can I take advantage of the fact that most of the entries in genotype are 0 to reduce this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you impute, information from the other columns are used to predict those in the columns with the missing data, so for example:

```
data3 = data.frame(matrix(runif(1000),ncol=10))
```

One of the steps in `mice` is to make a predictorMatrix and this is where it fails, using the example above:

```
make.predictorMatrix(data3,make.blocks(data3))
    X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
X1   0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
X2   1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
X3   1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
X4   1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1   1
X5   1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1   1
X6   1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   1
X7   1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1   1
X8   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1   1
X9   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0   1
X10  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   0
```

So if you have a input data that has 47992 columns, you will need a matrix that's 47992*47992 which is going to take up that much memory.

If I remember my genetics 101 correctly, the further your markers are away from each other, the less correlation you have, so maybe that's one way of trimming your columns.

Another option is to use [snpStats](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/snpStats/inst/doc/imputation-vignette.pdf), but quickly reading its vignette it seems like you have to specify some kinda rules anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Quick follow-up question: 47992*47992=2.3e9. That still leaves me an order of magnitude short of what the error message asked for. What accounts for the extra order of magnitude? Longer follow-up question coming.

Comment: I'm looking at a guide article to using mice by van Buuren and Groothuis-Oudshoorn. On p19, they start talking about the predictor matrix. In their example, they access the predictor matrix using imp <- mice(data,print=FALSE), followed by pred <- imp$predictorMatrix. They then change the predictor matrix, and then run the imputation again using imp <- mice(data,pred=pred,pri=FALSE). What does pri=FALSE mean? This isn't explained in the document, or in the even larger mice documentation pdf on CRAN.

Comment: You can run the predictor matrix on your data and you'll see the error. I am guessing pri is abbreviation for print.flag.

Comment: Yes, the memory overflow is indeed caused by the predictor matrix. Fortunately, I may be able to get around it using the Matrix package, and creating the predictor matrix as a sparse matrix.

What's a flag (in this context)?